# Adding a host to hosts file

Tags: apache, localhost, hosts

I'm trying to learn about hosts & apache a little bit. One of the things I'm trying to do myself is to add a line to /etc/hosts so that way I can access localhost in the browser

Currently, hosts contains this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Questions:
1. What does the ::1, and fe80::1%lo8 mean?
2. Are they essential to the accessing of 127.0.0.1 via typing 'localhost' in your browser?
3. What would I do to create an additional link to 127.0.0.1 typing something else in the browser, like "local", so that way both "localhost" and "local" work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kristian, I'm not sure what those symbols mean (::1 for example), but creating host file entries is as easy as typing an IP address and then the list of domains to match.

For example:

```
127.0.0.1 local localhost
```

will match both 'local' and 'localhost' to 127.0.0.1. You could have also done the following:

```
127.0.0.1 local
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

One entry per line - use a '#' at the beginning of each line if you want to comment that line out.

Answer (score 2):

The `::1` and `fe80` relate to IPv6 references to localhost.

To additional aliases like `local`, just chain them along in a space-separated list:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost local mylocalmachine someothername
```