# PowerShell Remote join to domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

Is it possible to add a computer remotely to a domain using PowerShell v2.0?  I'm aware of the Add-Computer CMDLET, but that is not for remote adding...but I maybe wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to call the [`Add-Computer`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347556.aspx) cmdlet via PowerShell remoting.

Comment: So you're saying remote using Remote Desktop and then run Add-Computer

Comment: No, I'm saying you should use [PowerShell Remoting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee706585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble to find out, so I will post it here briefly:

My problem was to access remote computer which was not on domain because it was not on domain... :) 
Something like Chicken and Egg problem.

Problem was described, discussed and solved here: [Powershell remoting with ip-address as target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587426/powershell-remoting-with-ip-address-as-target)

My quick fix is to run this command here.

```
    Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
```

You might want to backup currently trusted hosts and reset them after you bring your remote computer to domain.