# Write a powershell code which reads Excel and searches for attributes

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

I would like to write a code in powershell to read a csv file, which would read a list of IP addresses of various servers and search for the attributes: "Managed By", "Owner" of the server. Would this be possible? How would the code look like?

Im not familiar with powershell so I have not tried much yet.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to [SO]. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. SO isn't a free script writing service nor a forum, but a site for programmers helping colleagues who got stuck with a distinct problem. Own research and serious coding attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve] accompanied by samples of input and expected output. As PowerShell directly reads/imports `.csv` files, the tag Excel is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect anyone is going to write this code for you, but it'll be easier for you to find answers if you split it into parts:

1. [Read a CSV file in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682744/read-a-csv-file-with-powershell-and-capture-corresponding-data)
2. [Get a computer name from an IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242022/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-hostname-from-an-ip-address-without-depending-on-a-dns-i)
3. [Search Active Directory for a computer name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=winserver2012-ps)

Comment: Ahh no worries, the code was 10 lines, super simple (got someone on another forum website to explain it to me without down-voting me). lol people be making a huge deal as if this is a full on project.. arrogance is a big issue I see. But thanks for your breakdown :)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you. But people usually expect that you would give it a try yourself and ask for help if you run into a specific problem.