# Couldn't use Get-WinEvent from remote computer in VLAN

Tags: powershell, remote-debugging

The remote computer are Win-10 VM in a VLAN.
We only have a few ports open in VLAN, including 3389 for Remote Desktop, 5985 & 5986 for powershell.

Remote Desktop works well.

But I couldn't to use powershell to remote debug on those computers,

If I run

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName System -Credential domain\test_user -ComputerName 10.100.155.1
```

I get this error

```
Get-WinEvent : The RPC server is unavailable
```

If I use invoke-command to execute the same script,

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName 10.100.155.1 -Credential domain\test_user -ScriptBlock {Get-WinEvent -LogName System -Credential domain\test_user -ComputerName 10.100.155.1}`

I will get another error:

```
[10.100.155.1] Connecting to remote server 10.100.155.1 failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
```

I have tried many solutions on internet, unfortunately, none is working. For example, I have checked if the services are running,  if the firewall allows remote event management on remote computer, they looks alright.

Any idea where could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried passing a credential object into -Credential? $x = Get-Credential

Comment: RPC != WinRM...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell remoting with ip-address as target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587426/powershell-remoting-with-ip-address-as-target)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is two-fold.

1. You cannot use `WinRM` (`Invoke-Command`) with an IP address.  It uses Kerberos and Kerberos requires a DNS name.
2. You're passing your credentials and computername twice.

This should work without a problem:

```
$InvokeArgs = @{
    ComputerName = 'Computername.domain.com'
    Credential   = (Get-Credential -Credential domain\test_user)
    ScriptBlock  = { Get-WinEvent -LogName System }
}
Invoke-Command @InvokeArgs
```

Comment: Thanks.  But we don't use DNS for those machines, so they don't has DNS name. Outside VLAN,  I can only access them by IP address.  Any solution to this scenario?

Comment: I also tried to use Authentication = Negotiate, but I still get **Access Denied** Error

Comment: @Jim: psexec from sysinternals

Answer (score 0):

Access Denied is an Authentication Issue, double check your username and password.

I was working on a similar problem, trying to fetch count of system logons. Here's what worked for me:

```
$fetchEvents = { Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
Logname='system'
ProviderName='Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon'
StartTime=(get-date).AddDays(-10)
ID = 7001
} | Format-Table -Property TimeCreated, UserID, ID, MachineName }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ServerList -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock $fetchEvents
```