# Getting The Hostname,Current DATE and Time for remote server using IP address in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell scriptting and what it can do. I have an IP address of remote server and I want to retrieve the date and time of that on my local machine which is connected to it using cisco any connect . Can I do it using powershell.

Comment: Next time put a sample of your script, and people can help you modify it. That's sort of what stackoverflow is all about

Comment: can anyone from the community tell me why this question is getting so much negative votes and what should I improve while asking my next question

Comment: My comment above said why. Stack overflow is to help code get better. Not write code for you. So people get angry and downvote if you haven't "tried" already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, remoting through WinRM via IP, requires a `-credential` paramater value to be set. (Do this with `$admin = Get-Credential` and use `-credential $admin` as a parameter in the invoke-command)You can not remote via ip with your current credentials.  Also when using invoke command, I would HIGHLY suggest using `-sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofile)` otherwise you're creating profiles on every machine, which not only takes more time, but also leaves massive trails of your work.

E.g. (with Nas answer used)

```
$admin = Get-Credential
$remoteIP = 'x.x.x.x'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteIP -credential $admin -sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofile) -ScriptBlock {
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Get-Date
}
```

if you want to use a ton of machines, you could do this...

```
$admin = Get-Credential
$remoteIP = "x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x"
foreach ($pc in $remoteIP) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pc -credential $admin -sessionoption (new-pssessionoption -nomachineprofile) -ScriptBlock {
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{'Hostname'=$env:COMPUTERNAME
    'Date'=Get-Date}
}
}
```

to speed it up, i would remove "env:computername" as it should return pscomputername anyhow

this should be tons faster

```
$remoteIP = "x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x"
foreach ($pc in $remoteIP) {
    $object = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $pc -Property localdatetime,__server
    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{'computername'=$object.__server
                'Date'=$object.converttodatetime($object.localdatetime)}


}
```

__Server is TWO underscores than the word server. NOT _Server but __Server

[pscustomobject] is short for `new-object -typename psobject -property ...`

and [ordered] just ensures your hashtable order is preserved.

Comment: You don't need to loop through an array.  `-ComputerName` takes an array of strings already.

Comment: You are ABSOLUTELY correct. BUT, pscustomobject needs to handle one item at a time.

Comment: I also tried to get it to spit out date time and not need a forloop, but the select @{n;e} whole thing wouldn't work for me

Comment: Finally, `get-wmiobject` is such a root command, that it has zero impact on time(meaning to get it started). running it against localhost 1000 times(in an array), took 26.434 seconds with OUT a for loop, and 26.601 seconds with a for loop. finally, using pscustomobject on the latter made it 27.052 seconds. so 600 milliseconds per 1000 attempts. in other words it's negligible... the only benefit i could maybe see is if you set throttle limit maybe...tested it, and throttle limit had zero impact for me. Maybe on a network it might, but i can't test at this time

Comment: also note, function processes commands just like foreach loops by default, so if he turns it into a function, it will be 1 at a time from his input

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work if you have the necessary permissions and psremoting is enabled on the target server (Edit: convert ip to hostname)

```
$remoteIP = 'x.x.x.x'
$remoteServer = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($remoteIP)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $remoteServer.HostName -ScriptBlock {
    $env:COMPUTERNAME
    Get-Date
}
```

Try it and we can help you from there, depending on the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question ! I don't have permissions to send or run script request on server from ip communications. But I will try it as soon as I will get the permissions

Comment: Use `help about_Remote*` to get a list of documentation. `about_Remote_Requirements` is a good place to start.

Comment: Depending on why this doesn't work for you, this might also help [Powershell remoting with ip-address as target](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6667923/7554519)